# Php popen only returns bool(true) instead of a pointer

Tags: php, popen

I'm wondering that my simple popen() call only returns the boolean value TRUE instead of a resource.

Therefore the following fputs() throws a warnings like *"Warning: fputs() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given [...]"*

As described in the Php manual, I expect a resource/pointer or FALSE in return.

Here is my example:

```
$path = 'C:\path\to\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\sqlplus.exe';
$ph = popen($path,'w') || die ("Program not found");
fputs($ph, "username/password"\n");
```

Can anybody help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

`$ph = popen($path,'w') || die ("Program not found");` to `$ph = popen($path,'w');`

remove everything after `||` and try.

Also there is extra quote here : `fputs($ph, "username/password"\n");` remove one `fputs($ph, "username/password\n");`

Comment: Now, I'm annoyed at myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `||` syntax is still possible, just add parentheses to the first half.

```
($ph = popen($path,'w')) || die ("Program not found");
```